# Remove dead CSS frameworks from [css] tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, external-links

I was looking at the [CSS info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info) and noticed in the frameworks section that a few of them have been dead for a long time. For example, the Gumby framework has been dead for three years and there hasn't been a question about it for almost two years. Or Gridless boilerplate which has been dead for two years and only has one question that's from four years ago.

Shouldn't these links be removed, since they aren't maintained any more?

Comment: You'd have to ask the people who actually read these pages, to determine what kind of information they expect to be there. I'm not sure if a lot of people read them, I know I don't.

Answer (score 3):

From the Help Center, [Privileges > Approve Tag Wiki Edits - What are tag wikis?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits):

> Tag wikis are a general introduction to a topic defined by that tag. They're a place to consolidate and form a sub-community around a tag. They contain, among other things, frequently asked questions in the tag, top users in the tag, and best recent answers in the tag.

That does not necessarily include "a list of randomly picked sibling tags". So it's questionable whether that list should be in the wiki in the first place.

As explained in [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad), lists aren't very useful in general, **because they get outdated quickly**, Q.E.D.

The tag button on top of the framework list links to another tag wiki, namely that of [css-frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-frameworks), which contains a similar but barely intersecting list of CSS frameworks.

If it were up to me, I'd rewrite that entire list in the [css tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info) into something like this:

> **CSS Frameworks**
>
> A CSS Framework is a X that does Y and Z. See the tag [css-frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-frameworks) for questions about CSS frameworks.

And then I'd remove the list in the [css-frameworks tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-frameworks/info), or trim it down to the names of a handful long-living, well-matured, still maintained frameworks.

I say that because an incomplete list is worse than no list. Everybody can Google "css framework list" and come up with a different list than the ones submitted to both tags.

Comment: The CSS Info page is about 300% too long anyway, I support any effort to pare it down to size.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't these links be removed, since they aren't mantained anymore?

A FAQ kind of model should be pertinent. If there are useful Q&A pairs about these frameworks those links (which lead to Stack Overflow on site Q&A) shouldn't be deleted:

> > #### CSS Frameworks [css-frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-frameworks)
> >
> > - [960 Grid](//960.gs/) [960.gs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/960.gs)
> > - [Blueprint](//blueprintcss.org/) [blueprint-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blueprint-css)
> > - [Cascade Framework](//cascade-framework.com/) [cascade-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade-framework)
> > - [Columnal](//github.com/robertcedwards/Columnal) [columnal-css-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnal-css-framework)
> > - [Gridless boilerplate](//frankpf.github.io/gridless-boilerplate/)  [gridless-boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gridless-boilerplate)
> > - [Gumby][10] [gumby-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gumby-framework)
> > - [HTML5 ★ BOILERPLATE](//html5boilerplate.com/) [html5boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5boilerplate)
> > - [Inuit](//inuitcss.com/) [inuit.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inuit.css)
> >       ...

---

To give you another example:
The [turbo-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turbo-c%2b%2b) tag is about an ancient c++ compiler from the last millenium. Though there are still people that research and ask about it.

Comment: The point is not that tags to old frameworks exist. The issue is that the tag Wiki for the CSS tag mentions old, abandoned projects. I'd say clean 'em up.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, the point is that all of these are site links to still existing Q&A's see [Gumby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gumby-framework) for example. A tag-info wiki should make it easy to find them, and not judge about usefulness of old, outdated frameworks.

Comment: Yeah, and they're useless there. It's a tag Wiki, meant for relevant, up-to-date information about a tag, not necessarily links to all sibling tags of said tag.

Comment: @CodeCaster In how these links aren't _up-to-date_? They lead to ***existing*** information on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Turbo C++ ... man, we're old ....

Comment: @rene Well, it's still used in education frequently in India :P

Comment: But they don't. https://www.maxmert.com and https://blueprintcss.org are both dead. There is another blueprintcss framework now. But it's not on that link.

Comment: @ZeWebDev I'm more concentrated about the tag links. Old outdated links should be probably removed and replaced by a `XXX no longer active/available` text .